# Bind9 starts but won't listen to any ports

Tags: server, dns

I am getting nuts here...

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.6, and I am trying to get bind9 to work. But I do not succeed.

I started with removing systemd-resolved and added a ipv4 DNS directly to resolv.conf as a start.

Installed some needed stuff and bind9.

The problem is that bind9 starts as a service (systemctrl start|enable bind9), but is not binding to any ports. I have nothing else running on the ports for DNS. No problem in the config files, verified with named-checkconfig, and service starts - but no open ports...

I could really use som help here, if anyone have a minute!

```
root@ns3:~# systemctl status bind9
● bind9.service - LSB: Start and stop bind9
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/bind9; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2024-01-31 22:06:22 UTC; 7s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 611 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/bind9 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 31 22:04:11 ns3.*xxx*.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 22:04:12 ns3.*xxx*.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded.
Jan 31 22:04:12 ns3.*xxx*.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.*xxx*.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.*xxx*.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
```

```
root@ns3:~# ss -natulp
Netid     State       Recv-Q      Send-Q           Local Address:Port           Peer Address:Port     Process                               
udp       UNCONN      0           0                      0.0.0.0:1194                0.0.0.0:*         users:(("openvpn",pid=281,fd=4))     
tcp       LISTEN      0           128                    0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("sshd",pid=542,fd=3))        
tcp       LISTEN      0           20                   127.0.0.1:25                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("exim4",pid=536,fd=3))       
tcp       LISTEN      0           128                       [::]:22                     [::]:*         users:(("sshd",pid=542,fd=4))        
tcp       LISTEN      0           20                       [::1]:25                     [::]:*         users:(("exim4",pid=536,fd=4))
```

```
root@ns3:~# cat /etc/bind/named.conf
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";

root@ns3:~# cat /etc/bind/named.conf.options 
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;
    listen-on-v6 { none; };
    listen-on port 53 { 0.0.0.0/0; };
    auth-nxdomain yes;
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-transfer { aa.bb.cc.dd; aa.bb.cc.ee; };
};

root@ns3:~# cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local
zone "*xxx*.net" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/master/*xxx*.net";
};
```

```
Thanks a lot for answering, but I'm afraid the logs are not very enlightening...

Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded. Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded. Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded. Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 22:04:11 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 22:04:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded. Jan 31 22:04:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 22:04:25 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 22:04:25 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded. Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
```

```
and from syslog: Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3 systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded. Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3 systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded. Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3 systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded. Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 22:04:11 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 22:04:25 ns3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 22:04:25 ns3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3 systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded. Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9. Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9... Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
```

---

Thanks a lot for answering, but I'm afraid the logs are not very enlightening...

```
Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded.
Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded.
Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded.
Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 22:04:11 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 22:04:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded.
Jan 31 22:04:12 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 22:04:25 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 22:04:25 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded.
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3.xxx.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
```

and from syslog:

```
Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3 systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded.
Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:50:12 ns3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3 systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded.
Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:50:53 ns3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3 systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded.
Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 21:51:20 ns3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 22:04:11 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 22:04:25 ns3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 22:04:25 ns3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3 systemd[1]: bind9.service: Succeeded.
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop bind9.
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop bind9...
Jan 31 22:06:22 ns3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop bind9.
```

**EDIT**
I think I found it - bind9 is not a native service, but named is. Meaning "systemctl enable bind9" does not do it. I enabled named instead, which created a symlink named bind9.service in /etc/systemd/system/ (bind9.service -> /lib/systemd/system/named.service)

I have not had this problem before, but for some reason it ended up like this this time.

Sorry for bothering you guys!

---

Another thing that may be of interest, this is a VPS installation. I have another VPS with the same blend of Ubuntu, and that one works perfect.

Comment: Start with the syslog and output there.  Check the output of `journalctl -n 75 -u bind9.service` and see if there's any errors there.  If `bind9` is 'starting' but erroring out it might not show in the systemctl output but might show in thet specific journal or in `/var/log/syslog` and show you errors that otherwise are hidden.  The only reason `bind9` would start and then silently die and not listen on the ports is an error in your config or zone files or such somewhere.

Comment: @BjornE Please post the solution as an answer